# Can Gunther be defeated at the first confrontation?

Tags: deus-ex

After getting out of train station, I happen to confront Gunther (surrounded by UNATCO) with the decisions of surrender or fight.

I didn't have enough of my arsenal, one missile and one LAM grenade. I sometimes die by shooting the missile and by the looks feels as if he didn't get a scratch...

Can he be defeated in the named scene?

Comment: [Is this the same scene you talk about?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wC4-oW3wxM)

Comment: No. I mean the first confrontation, when I have the choice to surrender or to fight.

Comment: (I didn't reach the part you linked yet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the encounter with Gunther in battery park is one of the few instances, where you cannot kill a NPC. Gunther is invincible in this situation and the story will only progress once he got you.

Comment: 20 rockets and 20 LAMs later and he was still standing.

Comment: In comparison, everyone other boss dies in two rockets.